# How to find good state io stats?

Tags: linux, storage, nagios, iostat

I would like to monitor disk I/O activity in case something courses heavy I/O. [This](https://github.com/mclarkson/check_diskstat) Nagios plugin seams simple, where he gives examples of

```
Example: Tps, read and write thresholds:
    ./check_diskstat.sh -d sda -w 200,100000,100000 -c 300,200000,200000

Example: Average queue length threshold:
    ./check_diskstat.sh -d sda -W 50 -C 100
```

**Question**

Since different hosts will have different idle I/O activity, how can I find good starting values to use?

I guess another way to ask the same would be: Which `iostat` arguments should to use on each hosts to see what its "good state" disk I/O is?

Comment: I monitored the the load avg that include the iowait, if you have have a high IOWAIT you get a big loadavg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying counters are documented in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.txt

Setting meaningful thresholds based on the absolute number of IOPs and sectors read from or written to a block device (the lowercase  `-w` and `-c` options) requires a priori knowledge of the actual capabilities of that particular block device (for instance by benchmarking them).

Using the queue length (the UPPERcase  `-W` and `-C` options) seems a bit more universal. When you get an increased IO queue  that  is bad, regardless of how fast the underlying storage is, you're pushing more reads/writes than it can support and your applications will slow down.

I have no idea though if the documented 50 and 100 milliseconds are reasonable or completely arbitrary  values.

---

For my virtual servers using absolute numbers is relatively easy, they are provisioned in flavors  with [specific limits](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/pike/admin/flavors.html)   and I would only need to set the the warning/critical levels at for instance 80% respectively  95% of those assigned limits.

For example with a flavor 600 IOPS and 10 MB/s:

Divide the assigned `disk_read_bytes_sec` and `disk_write_bytes_sec` by 512 (the sector size) to get the limits in sectors the virtual disk will support. `(10 MB = 10000000 bytes)  / 512 = 19531`
19531 * 80% = 15624 and 600 * 80% = 480
19531 * 95% = 18749 and 600 * 95% = 570

```
./check_diskstat.sh -d vda -w 480,15624,15624 -c 570,18749,18749
```